# .htaccess Redirect Pattern

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm looking to redirect the pattern of a letter and up to two numbers (a12,d17) to (/home#d17, /home#a12).

There will be around 60 of these redirects so I was hoping a pattern could make things easier. Any ideas?

```
Redirect 301 /a1 /home#a1
Redirect 301 /d13 /home#d13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:
`Redirect 301 /([a-z][0-9]{1,2})$ /home#$1`

- `(` : start of capturing group 1
- `[a-z]` : match a letter (lowercase)
- `[0-9]{1,2}` : match one or two digits
- `)` : end of capturing group 1
- `$` : end of line

We'll use `$1` to reffer to group 1.

Comment: Made minor edit to allow for 1 or 2 digits instead of just two.

Answer (score 1):

Try this htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9])$ /home#$1 [R=301]
```